# SQL recurring date list with Start Date, On days, Off days & frequency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Looking to fill a table (SQL Server 2016) given the following data: start date (datetime), on days (int), off days (int), frequency for repeating interval (int)

Data - 1/1/2018, on = 7, off = 5, freq = 10

Output:

```
Date
1/1/2018
1/2/2018
1/3/2018
1/4/2018
1/5/2018
1/6/2018
1/7/2018
**skips 5**
1/13/2018
1/14/2018
1/15/2018
1/16/2018
1/17/2018
1/18/2018
1/19/2018
**skips 5** et. creating 7 and skipping 5 x 10
```

Realizing this can be done using loops, I was hoping there was a convenient CTE example, or other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like below. This solution is based on Tally/Numbers table approach.
To learn more about it read through the **[Jeff Moden article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)**

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/HSA43251)**</kbd>

```
declare @sd date= '01/01/2018', @on int= 7, @off int= 5, @freq int= 10;

select d
from
(
    select 
        top (@freq* (@on+@off))
        d=dateadd(d,row_number() over( order by (select null))-1 ,@sd),
        flag=case when row_number() over( order by (select null))%(@on+@off) between 1 and @on then 1 else 0 end
        from sys.objects o1
        cross join sys.objects o2
)t
where flag=1
```